# Construct wireframe model of a face image

Tags: opengl, opencv, wireframe

I want to write a program that will construct a wire-frame model of a face image and display it as 3d. Can any body help me about how to do this ?

I have some knowledge about **opencv** and **opengl**

Comment: This is really hard problem which implies a lot of technologies (image processing, feature tracking, point cloud reconstruction, 3D display, ...). Please refine your question to one or more so that we can try to help you.

Comment: actually I want that the program read a face image and construct a 3d wire-frame model like **candide parameterized face model** [link](http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/)

Comment: Any success with displaying a candid wire frame ?