# How to implement Facial Action Coding System (FACS)?

Tags: matlab, opengl, animation, opencv, 3d

I am trying to simulate facial expressions similar to [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrgNKGjSyxA&feature=player_detailpage#t=16s)

I have understood the FACS - action units i.e., units to be moved for a certain expression.

But I have no idea how to move/deform the action units to simulate expression in Matlab/OpenCV/OpenGL.

I have a 3D face mesh with neutral expression. I want to deform this face to simulate various expressions like in the above video.

Can anyone point me some references on how to approach the problem??

Answer (score 4):

You can check **"Anthropometric model"** in this [link](http://aifi.isr.uc.pt/Downloads.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link.... I have seen one of your [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129745/construct-wireframe-model-of-a-face-image) ... Have you solved it.. I exactly need the same now... If possible, can you expand your answer...

Comment: Sure.You said that, you have a 3D face mesh.. did you program it or find some where ? if possible send the link.

Comment: I used [**basel face model**](http://faces.cs.unibas.ch/bfm/main.php?nav=1-1-0&id=details) ... It is available for download for academic research...